# Nested ngRepeat with function call using parent property as parameter displaying wrong lists

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a nested ng-repeat that displays a seemingly random list of the possible ones I get.

My HTML is like this:

```
<table ng-init="getHouses()">
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="h in houses>
        <td>{{h.Id}}</td>
        <td>{{h.Name}}</td>
        <td ng-init="peopleInhHouse(h.Id)">
             <span ng-repeat="p in peopleInHouse">p.Name</span>
             <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I think the problem lies here because I get my lists of people correctly, the problem being that it displays the same list of people for all the different houses and it seems to randomize between everytime I refresh the page.

Comment: can you create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) for it. I guess you can use filter in your second ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `peopleInHouse` will always reference to the same value. And since you are using a request to get data you can't simply use it directly in the `ng-repeat`

So just update the `ng-init` function so it populates the people in the house

The function should look something like

```
function addPeopleToHouse(house){
  request(house.id).then(function(response){
    house.People = response.data;
  })
}
```

And update the HTML to

```
<td ng-init="addPeopleToHouse(h)">
    <span ng-repeat="p in h.People">p.Name</span>
   <br />
</td>
```

Comment: @Benji you should provided the info that `peopleInhHouse` is getting data from the server. I think this goes towards your initial approach